# How to implement SharePoint Migration (Metadata Asynchronous Read) Export API

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration, migrationapi

I need to fetch metadata from SharePoint Online site using SharePoint Migration (Metadata Asynchronous Read) Export API. How to initiate the code and what are dependent dlls / packages are required?

Please guide me.